# combining drawCircle on map click and displaying multiple markers at the same time and also showing markers which fall under the circle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geometry

I am making a web application to track assets and I need to show the location of assets using the database. I have written a code for that and it works fine. Now  I need to show the assets which are within a variable radius of 200 to 2000 m. I have written the code for variable circle when clicked on any location on map and it can be dragged any where (code separately written on two different pages) . I need help to combine both. I tried doing so but failed and got confused. Please help. The backend is C# and ASP.NET. Any thing else please ask!!
This is code for plotting markers from database

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var markers = [
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            {
                "Name": '<%# Eval("AID") %>',
                "lat": '<%# Eval("Current_Location_Y") %>',
        "lng": '<%# Eval("Current_Location_X") %>',
            "description": '<%# Eval("Description") %>',
            "CCId": '<%# Eval("CCID") %>'

       }

</ItemTemplate>
<SeparatorTemplate> 
    ,

</SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater >


  ];

</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">  
  window.onload = function initMap() {                                

    var mapOptions = {                           
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),  
        zoom: 16,                                                     
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP ,                  
  navigationControl: true
    };
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow/*()*/;                   
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);   
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {                                   
        var data = markers[i]                                               
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);              
 switch (data.CCId) {
            case "1":
                icon = "images/red-dot.png";
                break;
            case "3":
                icon = "images/yellow-dot.png";
                break;
            case "2":
                icon = "images/green-dot.png";
                break;
            default:
                icon = "images/Google Maps Markers/red_markerC.png";
        }
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({                  
            position: myLatlng,                                
            map: map,                                        
            draggable: true,
            title: data.title                             
        });
      (function (marker, data) {                            
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {   
                infoWindow.setContent(data.Name);                    
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);                      
                               });
        })(marker, data);         
    }
}

 </script>
```

This is the draw circle function which shows a draggable circle and a marker when clicked anywhere on the map.

```
 <script>
    var map;
    var circle;
    var marker;
    var currentlatlng;
    function setLatLongValue() {
        jQuery('#txtPointA1').val(currentlatlng.lat()); //#txtPointA1
        jQuery('#txtPointA2').val(currentlatlng.lng());
    }
    function loadMap() {

        currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.06368, 72.53135);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 16,
            center: currentlatlng,
            mapTypeId: 'terrain',
            mapTypeControl: true,
            navigationControl: true
        });
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'click', function (e) {

            currentlatlng = e.latLng;

            if (currentlatlng) {

                map.panTo(currentlatlng);
                setLatLongValue();
                setMarker();
            }
        });
    }
        function drawCircle() {

            if (circle != undefined)
                circle.setMap(null);

            var radius = 200;

            if (jQuery('#txtPointB1').val() != '' && !isNaN(jQuery('#txtPointB1').val()) && parseInt(jQuery('#txtPointB1').val()) > 0) {
                radius = parseInt(jQuery('#txtPointB1').val());
            }
            jQuery('#txtPointB1').val(radius.toString());

            var options = {
                strokeColor: '#800000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillColor: '#C64D45',
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                map: map,
                center: currentlatlng,
                radius: radius
            };

            circle = new google.maps.Circle(options);
        } 
        function setMarker() {

            if (marker != undefined)
                marker.setMap(null);

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: currentlatlng,
                draggable: true,
                map: map
            });

            if (marker) {
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
                    currentlatlng = marker.getPosition();
                    setLatLongValue();
                    drawCircle();
                });
                drawCircle();
            }
        }   

</script>
   <script type="text/javascript" >

        $(window).load(function () {
            loadMap();
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://hypocampus.applications.uwa.edu.au/) is an example of how I do it.

To see the demo you need to preload your browser with the coordinates: -
                latitude: -31.98118
                longitude: 115.81991

*OR* tap/click the Radar icon (bottom right), make the circle very big, zoom out a lot, then drag the circle to UWA in Perth Western Australia. Then zoom back in.

You need to do the above 'cos there is only data for the UWA campus.

You will see that as you drag the circle around campus green gems appear in the circle and disappear when the circle leaves.

Tap to remove the circle. Double-Tap to toggle from a movable circle to a static quadrangle. Tap-and-hold to get the search filter options.

The searching is done in a Web Worker to allow the main-thread to service the UI promptly.

Comment: This is awesome but I am  able to do so individually but together i am not able to. what changes in the code is needed? Please help.

Comment: Amazing! will surely try this.